# How to start a Haskell Process out Runtime.getRuntime.exec() ? And Communicate interactively?

Tags: java, haskell, communication, interactive

Hi I created a Process and now want to execute an haskell programm through Runtime.exec and communicate with the Process interactively.

For example i would like to start a haskell programm like

ghci

f a b = a * b

f 2 3

now if i use something like

theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ghci");

and can´t do something like this afterwards.

theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("let f a b = a *b"); 
also

theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ghci | let f a b = a *b")

wont work.

How can I communicate and execute commands on the same process without a bash file.

thx for your help hope I explained my problem well

Answer (score 1):

You need to communicate via the stdin/stdout streams to achieve what you want. Buit it is not quite easy, you need some well defined protocol to avoid deadlocks, etc.

But I have something for you, tat may better suit your needs: just in case you do not know, there is a language called [Frege](https://github.com/Frege), which is nearly Haskell 2010 and compiles to Java code. It also has JSR 223 Scripting support, so you could just run and evaluate expressions from your java code.

Comment: I really have to use java . the basic idea is that a client can send a haskell file to the server which works as the compiler and works as a bridge for communication.

Comment: That is what I am saying: you use Java, and call a script via scripting support. Chances are that Frege will interpret and run your scriupt just like Haskell would, unless it uses certain non-supported GHC extensions or libraries.

Comment: If hat is not an option, I'd suggest to first compile the haskell file with ghc, then to run the executable.

Comment: BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
w.write("let f a b = a + b \n");
w.flush();

That does the trick . Even though its quite tricky. Thx anyway :)